# Meteor publishing additional user information login / logout

Tags: coffeescript, meteor, meteorite

I'm trying to selectively publish user data depending on the role of the user. I want email addresses to be published, and the user name. If the user is an admin, they should be able to see the whole user profile.

On the server (CS):

```
Meteor.publish "allUsers", ->
    if Roles.userIsInRole @userId, 'admin' then data = profile: 1
    else data = 'profile.name': 1
    data['emails.address'] = 1
    Meteor.users.find {}, fields: data
```

On the client (CS):

```
Meteor.subscribe("allUsers")
```

This works great most of the time. When a user logs out, and then logs in again, something is broken with the subscription and

```
Meteor.user().profile
```

returns nothing. Refreshing the page, and the profile field is filled in again. To try to fix the problem, I changed the server return statement to:

```
[
    Meteor.users.find {}, fields: data
    Meteor.users.find @userId
]
```

this did nothing. Is this a bug with Meteor or am I fundamentally misunderstanding the login/logout?

**Update**

I read a bit more and it seems that Meteor will randomly choose data for multiple subscriptions / publishes on the same collection. With that in mind, I changed the return query to:

```
Meteor.users.find _id: $ne: @userId, fields: data
```

The data from the other users is now not published! (Meteor.users.find().count() in console returns 1.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your original return statement is fine. However, I would look at what happens with your `Roles.userIsInRole`function when `@userId` is `null`. Maybe there's a bug there that's causing the Publish function to crash.

I'm not a Coffeescripter, but if that's the problem, then I think adding this  the top of your Publish function would resolve your problem:

```
if not @userId return
```

Comment: The publish function isn't crashing. All that happens when the userId is null is that Roles.userIsInRole returns undefined, which means the else statement is hit. This doesn't begin to solve the problem - an anonymous user should still have access to this information. Returning if there is no userId will mean that doesn't happen. Even though I knew this wouldn't work, I checked: logout, and then login again (as predicted) still leaves the profile field unpopulated. Thanks for trying.

Comment: ah okay, yeah I wasn't sure if you wanted anonymous users to get that info or not. I would log the value of _data_ right before you call Meteor.users.find(). If you don't have a server-side debugging tool set-up, simply using console.log() will output to the terminal(a.k.a. command prompt) where you started up Meteor. Check not only the value, but make sure the Publish function is actually being called after each action (logging in/logging out)

Comment: I have logged the value of data before calling... And of course the publish function is called on login / logout, that's what happens! This really isn't the source of the issue. It's something to do with multiple subscriptions on the same collection.